# The result being cast to double in Pig but is still being ordered as a string

Tags: casting, apache-pig

I encountered the following problem:

First my data is a string that looks like this: 
decimals, decimals

example: `1.345, 3.456`

I used the following pig script to put this column, say QQ, into two columns:

```
result = FOREACH old_table GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(QQ, ',')) as (COL1: double, COL2: double);
```

Then, I want to order it by first field, then second field.

```
result_ordered = ORDER result BY COL1, COL2;
```

However, I got the result like the following:

```
> 59.619198977071434    -151.4586740547339
> 60.52611316847121 -150.8005347076273
> 64.8310014577408  -147.84786488835852
> 7.059652849999997 125.59985130999996
```

which implies that my data is still being ordered as a string and not as a double. Has anyone encountered this issue and know how to solve it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why STRSPLIT is returning a chararray though you explicitly state they are doubles.  But if you look at http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#arithmetic, notice that chararrays can't be multiplied by 1.0 to doubles, but bytearrays can.  Therefore you can do something like:

```
result = FOREACH old_table 
       GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(QQ, ',')) AS (COL1: bytearray, COL2: bytearray);

B = FOREACH result GENERATE 1.0 * COL1 AS COL1, 1.0 * COL2 AS COL2 ;

result_ordered = ORDER B BY COL1, COL2;
```

Which gives me the correct output of:

```
result_ordered: {COL1: double,COL2: double}
(7.059652849999997,125.59985130999996)
(59.619198977071434,-151.4586740547339)
(60.52611316847121,-150.8005347076273)
(64.8310014577408,-147.84786488835852)
```

Comment: Oh Wow! Didn't expect this at all! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the output of `FLATTEN` to a schema with two doubles, try actually casting the fields with `(chararray)`.  It may be that Pig only uses the `:chararray` syntax for applying schema checking, but requires the explicit cast to convert the types during execution.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just actually tried that. For some reason, it still does not work. 

Just FYI, what I ended up doing to solve this is that after FLATTENing, I store this into a file. Then, I load the file again with the columns as doubles and it works. However, this induces a huge processing cost.